Error with apt-mirror
I managed to make it work perfectly well together with nginx, but when I tried adding more versions (for now I only had noble and I wanted to add oracular and the apt-mirror command stopped working showing the following
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble/main/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble/restricted/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble/universe/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble/multiverse/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-security/main/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-security/restricted/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-security/universe/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-security/multiverse/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-updates/main/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-updates/restricted/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-updates/universe/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
apt-mirror: can't open index archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//dists/noble-updates/multiverse/binary-<running/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 891, <STREAM> chunk 61596.
Processing indexes: [PPP]

I saw some similar posts and tried the solutions they proposed in those same ones but at the moment none of them worked, that's why I'm asking for help.

Please edit your post and show your complete mirror.list
